# Three.js: Scaling objects created with Blender

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I have a problem with scaling objects. I created the model of a table with blender. Now I add every sub-object (4 table legs and 1 table top) to the scene:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( 'obj/self/testcube5.obj', 'obj/self/testcube5.mtl', function ( object ) {  
    var i = 0;
    while(object.children[0] != undefined)
    {
        var cc = object.children[0];
        scene.add(cc);
    }
});
```

Goal is to scale parts of the table while repositioning other parts. E.g. make the legs longer and lift the table top.

Scaling the table legs:

```
function keyPressed (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 87) 
    { // W
        for(var i=0; i<scene.children.length; i++)
        {
            if(scene.children[i].name.indexOf("tischbein") > -1)
            {
                scene.children[i].scale.set(x, y, z+=0.01);     
            }
        } 
    } 
    else if (event.keyCode === 83) 
    { // S
        for(var i=0; i<scene.children.length; i++)
        {
            if(scene.children[i].name.indexOf("tischbein") > -1)
            {
                scene.children[i].scale.set(x, y, z-=0.01);     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem one:
- If I scale the legs that way, the table top gets scaled (and translated), too.

Problem two:
- If I try to scale only one leg...

```
if(scene.children[i].name.indexOf("tischbein1") > -1)
{
    // scale table leg "tischbein1" ...
}
```

... no leg gets scaled but the table top lifts up.

[Example page](http://webgl.pauly.io/webgl_loader_obj_mtl2.html) (use mouse)

It's a very strange behaviour I can't handle and I don't really understand. 
What do I have to change to be able to access and manipulate every single sub-object without manipulating any other object in the scene?